# Where should i save a local JSON file in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to JSON files and am looking into them. Where should I put the file in my iOS/Xcode project and what code should I use to access it?

Comment: Are you talking about a read-only file you package with your app or are you talking about a file downloaded at runtime that you wish to save in the app's sandbox? BTW - The answer to your question has nothing to do with it being a JSON file. The answer is same for any type of file.

Comment: A read only file packaged with my app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've dropped mine into a folder I called Resources:

[image]

But you can put in anywhere you want, as long as it makes sense to you, your team, or developers who will continue working on this project.

And I access it in my AppDelegate like this:

```
public func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let fileName: String = "all"
    if let jsonPath = mainBundle.pathForResource(fileName, ofType: ".json", inDirectory: nil, forLocalization: nil), jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonPath)
    {
        if let json: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: nil), data = json.valueForKey("data") as? [AnyObject]
        {
            // do whatever you want with your JSON file
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
if let jsonPath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "all", ofType: "json"), let jsonData: Data = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonPath) as? Data {
  do {
      let json: AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
      if let data: Array<AnyObject> = json.value(forKeyPath: "data") as? Array<AnyObject> {
          // do whatever you want with the content of your json file
      }        
  } catch {
      print("Error while deserialization of jsonData")
  }
}
```

Comment: I've removed `setupAppearance()` since it is specific to my code. What error do you get now?

Comment: I still get the same error for the line that you didn't remove

Comment: I've updated my code so that it easier to understand

Comment: if in the json file there is a dictionary and he key for a certain value is "feeling" how would get the value